# MySQL - Matching ID to Max of Count ("Need" more elegant solution)

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a better way to do the following:

```
SELECT ProductID, MAX(a.countProductID)
FROM
    (
    SELECT ProductID, COUNT(ProductID) as countProductID
    FROM    SalesOrderDetail
            LEFT JOIN Product USING (ProductID)
    GROUP BY ProductID
    ) as a
WHERE a.countProductID =    (SELECT MAX(x.countProductID) FROM
                            (
                                SELECT ProductID, COUNT(ProductID) as countProductID
                                FROM    SalesOrderDetail
                                        LEFT JOIN Product USING (ProductID)
                                GROUP BY ProductID
                            ) as x
                            );
```

Since im using the same subquery twice. However i can't access the first one from the WHERE clause.

Comment: I mean you could use a view?

Comment: Its an exercise for a class. (However there was only a question. My provided code is completely from me and I don't want you to finish my course homework)

Views might be what my professor wants me to use.
However I've slept through some classes and have no idea what that is :$

Could you point me to a resource to learn it?

Comment: So what do you want then?

Comment: what is the where clause doing for you? "WHERE a.countProductID =    (SELECT MAX(x.co..."

Comment: @WhyCry What i posted is pretty much already a correct answer, however im not satisfied with it and want to make it "smarter". I guess thats where i have to use views. Going to google it. I just thought you might know a good resource.  

@ bowlturner It is filtering for the correct id, otherwise it will show a random id.

Comment: Your query returns an indeterminate `productId` with the maximum of the count.  There are, indeed, better ways to write that.  However, I suspect that is not what you really want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final answer

```
SELECT ProductID, COUNT(ProductID) as countProductID 
FROM    SalesOrderDetail
LEFT JOIN Product USING (ProductID)
GROUP BY ProductID
ORDER BY countProductID desc
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: He wants top 1 with ties as in `sql server`

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri . . . What would give you that idea?  His query returns one row with an indeterminate product.  The original version of this query was a fine interpretation of the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, in where clause he is picking max of counts of products. In select he selects count of products and filters by max count in where clause. I think it is top 1 with ties.

Comment: @JohnRW Are there multiple products with the same count?

Comment: Thanks bowlturner =) Now it works :) 

There indeed are 2 products with the top count, however the assignment from my professor asks for one.. He has a lot of questions like that... The answer you gave before gave back an id with a count of 7, however the top two products have a count of 10. Now it works however. Thanks a lot

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri . . . There is no `group by` in the outer query and the `count()` turns it into an aggregation query.  The query returns only one row with an indeterminate `productid` (that matches the other conditions) in MySQL (and an error in any other database).  We can all try to figure out what the OP *really* means, but the query is pretty clear.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the task is to find product or products with the maximum sales count. First you shouldn't join with `PRODUCT` table because all information you need is in `SalesOrderDetail` table. Then use `LIMIT 1` to find maximum count and `HAVING` to select all products with maximum count:

```
SELECT ProductID, COUNT(ProductID) as countProductID
FROM    SalesOrderDetail
GROUP BY ProductID
HAVING COUNT(ProductID) = (SELECT COUNT(ProductID) as countProductID 
                             FROM SalesOrderDetail 
                           GROUP BY ProductID 
                           ORDER BY countProductID DESC
                           LIMIT 1 )
```

Comment: That works too. Thanks. It even gives back both top counting products, which would be even more correct. However my professor only asked for one... You get a upvote, too, because your answer is smarter than my professors question ;D